# Akka HTTP: Unmarshal to class with generic type parameter

Tags: json, scala, akka, akka-http

I have the following class

```
case class PaginatedSearchResult[T : RootJsonFormat](pages: Option[Page], objects: Option[Seq[T]])

object PaginatedSearchResult extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val format = jsonFormat2(PaginatedSearchResult.apply)
}
```

I am attempting to unmarshal it like so:

```
Unmarshal(response.entity).to[PaginatedSearchResult[T]]
```

This is the error I get

```
Error:(15, 59) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type spray.json.RootJsonFormat[T]
  implicit val format = jsonFormat2(PaginatedSearchResult.apply)
```

I am trying to figure out how to get this to unmarshal correctly. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems:

When you define `jsonFormat2(PaginatedSearchResult.apply)`, you're missing implicit value of type `RootJsonFormat[T]` as it is required in your constructor/apply method. Compiler cannot possible know it for any `T` and gives you error

```
Error:(15, 59) could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type spray.json.RootJsonFormat[T]
```

You can fix it by defining format as a `def`

```
implicit def format[T: RootJsonFormat] = jsonFormat2(PaginatedSearchResult.apply)
```

Second problem is the place where you require the format to be used

```
Unmarshal(response.entity).to[PaginatedSearchResult[T]]
```

In this case you have to use a concrete `T` or have `RootJsonFormat[T]` available in the implicit scope.

You could do this

```
def unmarshal[T: RootJsonFormat] = { 
  Unmarshal(response.entity).to[PaginatedSearchResult[T]]
}
```

And use it as `unmarshal[User]` if you have a type `User` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this with the following code:

```
case class PaginatedSearchResult[T : JsonFormat](pages: Option[Page], objects: Option[Seq[T]])

object PaginatedSearchResult extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit def format[T : JsonFormat]: RootJsonFormat[PaginatedSearchResult[T]] = jsonFormat2(PaginatedSearchResult.apply[T])
}
```